# Is there a better way to get the labels as a list of those features (columns) with non a single missing values in a data frame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am playing with some data set from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/). I would like to get all the columns labels (features) as a list of those features with non a single missing values

. I have done it (I think so) but I wonder if there is a better way to do it. Here is my code, **result** is a list of those features with non a single missing values :

```
    import matplotlib as plt
    data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\.kaggle\house-prices\train.csv')
    result = data.isnull().sum(axis=0)[data.isnull().sum(axis=0) == 
    0].index.tolist()
```

For example, if I run the following code:

```
    d = { 'Feature 1': [None, 1, 2, None ], 'Feature 2': [4, 5, 5, 6], 
    'Feature 3': [7, 7, 8, 9 ]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
    print(df
    print(df.isnull().sum(axis=0)[df.isnull().sum(axis=0) == 
    0].index.tolist())
```

I will get the following result:

```
       Feature 1  Feature 2  Feature 3
    0        NaN          4          7
    1        1.0          5          7
    2        2.0          5          8
    3        NaN          6          9

    ['Feature 2', 'Feature 3']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and convert columns names to `list`:

```
print (df.dropna(axis=1).columns.tolist())
['Feature 2', 'Feature 3']
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.dropna(axis=1))
   Feature 2  Feature 3
0          4          7
1          5          7
2          5          8
3          6          9
```

Answer (score 1):

`notnull` + `all`

```
df.notnull().all().loc[lambda x : x].index.tolist()
Out[449]: ['Feature 2', 'Feature 3']
```

Comment: Thank you . The only bit missing is `.tolist()` at the end

Comment: @Masaguaro yep, fixed '

Comment: I am trying to understand your answer. The purpose of `.loc[lambda x : x]` is to return  `df.notnull().all()` as a Pandas Series ?

Comment: @Masaguaro df.notnull().all() this will return F T T , and you only want to have all not null value , so I am using .loc to select the row we need (since the x in loc is already bool type )

Comment: I see @Wen. Interesting tool, for anybody interested [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is the explanation. Look for this example: `df.loc[lambda df: df['shield'] == 8]`